# Fragments overlapping in Android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment, overlapping

I'm trying to switch between fragments without losing the previous contents, so I decided to implement this way to do it:

```
private void loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().hide(fragment);
    if (!alreadyOpened[currentIndex]) {
        alreadyOpened[currentIndex] = true;
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container,fragment).commit();
    } else {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().show(fragment).commit();
    }
}
```

With this method I check if a fragment has been already opened: if yes, I show it, if not I add it. Then I declare it as "alreadyOpened". The problem is that when I switch between fragments I see all the three fragments overlapping. How can I solve it?
This is the menu bar when I invoke the loadFragment method:

```
private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
        = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.bbn_item1:
                currentIndex = 0;
                loadFragment(new HomeFragment());
                return true;
            case R.id.bbn_item2:
                currentIndex = 1;
                loadFragment(new PopularFragment());
                return true;
            case R.id.bbn_item3:
                 currentIndex = 2;
                loadFragment(new PlayingFragment());
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

EDIT: new code

```
List<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>();

private void loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    if (alreadyOpened[currentIndex]) {
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragments.get(currentIndex));
    } else {
        fragments.add(currentIndex, fragment);
        alreadyOpened[currentIndex] = true;
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
    }
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commit();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not created new Fragments on every navigation click. created once somewhere and save them in `List<Fragment> fragments` array. and after that use `fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_layout, fragment);` here is little example:

```
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_left); //optional 
    ft.replace(R.id.fragment_layout, fragments.get(selectedFragment));
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commit();
```

From your `onNavigationItemSelected` send `selectedFragment` variable, and match the position in the `fragments` list.

Edit:
how about this:

```
public HomeFragment homeFragment;
public PopularFragment popularFragment;
public PlayingFragment playingFragment;

private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
    = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.bbn_item1:
           if(homeFragment == null){ homeFragment  =new HomeFragment();}
           loadFragment(homeFragment )
            return true;
        case R.id.bbn_item2:
            if(homeFragment == null){ popularFragment  =new PopularFragment();}
            loadFragment(popularFragment)
            return true;
        case R.id.bbn_item3:
             if(homeFragment == null){ playingFragment  =new PlayingFragment();}
            loadFragment(playingFragment);
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

};

```
public void loadFragment(Fragment fragment){
  FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_left); //optional 
    ft.replace(R.id.fragment_layout, fragment);
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commit();

}
```

Comment: With this method I do not restore what I did in the fragments before switching them, right? For example: I've a fragment where the user can search for an item. If I switch fragment I lose the list of items found and I return to the search bar. This what I want to avoid

Comment: I believe so. fragment's OnCreate function is called then you're are creating new fragment like: new  MyFragment() not when you are binding on your layout with FragmentTransaction. So you should not loose your progress. try it, if you loose we can work around it too.

Comment: I updated the question with the new code, unfortunately nothing changed

Comment: It keeps refreshing the content of the fragments.

Comment: I don't know man I have same working version and it does not refresh even recyclerview content. What kind of content do you want?

Comment: With your method I noticed that if I write something in the search bar of an activity it remains when switch between fragments. The problem is that the list of elements inside it gets refreshed every time. Do I need to override method like onResume etc.. in the fragments?

Comment: yes you can override onAttach() function which will be called on every time fragment will be attached. in it recall your search function with value of your  EditText. and then call notifyDatasetChange() on your recyclerview.